# How to solve 'Cannot find contract attachments' exception in Corda 4 upgrade

Tags: corda

I upgraded to Corda 4 and now I'm getting the following exception when running my flow tests:

```
net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for my.package.Contractnull
```

This is part of the code that I have in the mock network setup:

```
fun setup() {
        network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
                cordappWithPackages("my.package"),
                enclosedCordapp()
        ))) ... }
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when running one of my flows and the problem was with the contract ID.

It was with a different name from the class.

```kotlin
class YourAwesomeContract : Contract {
  companion object {
    // Used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
    const val ID = "markets.imperium.contracts.NotSoAwesomeId"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got multiple JARs with the `my.package` root namespace? The MockNetwork searches for a single jar with that namespace - it could be that there are multiples and it is picking up the wrong one. You need to specify a package namespace that identifies the JAR you want to include uniquely.